# Adding NA values for time gaps less than a certain time in R

Tags: r, time, time-series, na

I have a dataframe (df; see below) with positions over a time series (multiple years, positions are given each hour). There are a lot of gaps in the data, and while I plan to run a model to estimate some of the missing positions, I need to remove gaps that are greater than 10 hours because I cannot estimate over this length of time (i.e. keep gaps that are 10 hours or less).

The dataset does not have NA values for these datetime gaps. Thus, I have to first create NA rows for each datetime that is missing within the specified date range (the data are from September 01 to December 01 in each year), then remove rows where NA gaps are greater than 10 hours.

I will have to run this analysis with different thresholds for time, and with multiple datasets. Thus, instead of making this a two-step process, is it possible to only add NA values for a specific time gap size (add NAs for time gaps that are 10 hours or less)? This would then eliminate the need to remove time gaps greater than 10 hours.

Here are some example data:

```
table <- "id    date     time      lat       lon
1  A 2011-10-03 05:00:00 35.02957 -53.36053
2  A 2011-10-03 06:00:00 35.11430 -53.39990
3  A 2011-10-03 09:00:00 35.14563 -53.40357
4  A 2011-10-03 10:00:00 36.22431 -53.57891
5  A 2011-10-03 23:00:00 36.60950 -53.56792
6  B 2012-11-08 05:00:00 35.84570 -53.36992
7  B 2012-11-08 07:00:00 35.99980 -53.36084
8  B 2012-11-08 10:00:00 36.45001 -53.37093
9  B 2012-11-08 23:00:00 36.56789 -53.38654
10 B 2012-11-09 05:00:00 36.62456 -53.50901"

#Create a dataframe with above table
df <- read.table(text=table, header = TRUE)
df
```

And here is what the expected output would be:

```
table2 <- "id    date     time      lat       lon
1  A 2011-10-03 05:00:00 35.02957 -53.36053
2  A 2011-10-03 06:00:00 35.11430 -53.39990
3  A 2011-10-03 07:00:00 NA       NA
4  A 2011-10-03 08:00:00 NA       NA
5  A 2011-10-03 09:00:00 35.14563 -53.40357
6  A 2011-10-03 10:00:00 36.22431 -53.57891
7  A 2011-10-03 23:00:00 36.60950 -53.56792
8  B 2012-11-08 05:00:00 35.84570 -53.36992
9  B 2011-11-08 06:00:00 NA       NA
10 B 2012-11-08 07:00:00 35.99980 -53.36084
11 B 2011-11-08 08:00:00 NA       NA
12 B 2011-11-08 09:00:00 NA       NA
13 B 2012-11-08 10:00:00 36.45001 -53.37093
14 B 2012-11-08 23:00:00 36.56789 -53.38654
15 B 2011-11-09 00:00:00 NA       NA
16 B 2011-11-09 01:00:00 NA       NA
17 B 2011-11-09 02:00:00 NA       NA
18 B 2011-11-09 03:00:00 NA       NA
19 B 2011-11-09 04:00:00 NA       NA
20 B 2012-11-09 05:00:00 36.62456 -53.50901"

#Create a dataframe with the above table
expected <- read.table(text=table2, header = TRUE)
expected
```

Edit:

I should add that this code also needs to consider that there are different IDs, and time gaps should be considered for each ID separately, not across all IDs (e.g. time gaps should not be added between lines 5 and 6, because that is a time gap between two different IDs).

Edit 2:

The answer by Ronak Shah works. However, sometimes I will also have to run this code using minutes. For example, the time intervals would be every 30 minutes, and I would want to keep gaps of 1 hour/60 mins (two 30-min intervals), but not gaps that are more than that. Is it possible to adapt the answer by Ronak Shah for this?

I've tried changing the units to "mins", the >10 to ">60" and leaving the "hour" in the second line, but that just gives me an NA line for every hour in the gap, when I really want an NA for every 30-min gap unless there are more than two 30-min gaps in that hour. I've tried other iterations as well, that leave me with many NAs, when I really only want one every 30 minutes, and only if it is an hour or less of a gap.

```
df %>%
  unite(datetime, date, time, sep = ' ') %>%
  mutate(datetime = lubridate::ymd_hms(datetime)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(difftime(datetime, lag(datetime, default = first(datetime)), units = 'mins') > 60), .add = TRUE) %>%
  complete(datetime = seq(min(datetime), max(datetime), by = 'hour')) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

Combine `date` and `time` column to create datetime for each `id` create a `grp` column that creates a new group for time value which is within 10 hours. Use `complete` to create missing hourly sequence between minimum and maximum time in each group.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  unite(datetime, date, time, sep = ' ') %>%
  mutate(datetime = lubridate::ymd_hms(datetime)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(difftime(datetime, lag(datetime, default = first(datetime)), units = 'hours') > 10), .add = TRUE) %>%
  complete(datetime = seq(min(datetime), max(datetime), by = 'hour')) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)

#   id    datetime              lat   lon
#   <chr> <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A     2011-10-03 05:00:00  35.0 -53.4
# 2 A     2011-10-03 06:00:00  35.1 -53.4
# 3 A     2011-10-03 07:00:00  NA    NA  
# 4 A     2011-10-03 08:00:00  NA    NA  
# 5 A     2011-10-03 09:00:00  35.1 -53.4
# 6 A     2011-10-03 10:00:00  36.2 -53.6
# 7 A     2011-10-03 23:00:00  36.6 -53.6
# 8 B     2012-11-08 05:00:00  35.8 -53.4
# 9 B     2012-11-08 06:00:00  NA    NA  
#10 B     2012-11-08 07:00:00  36.0 -53.4
#11 B     2012-11-08 08:00:00  NA    NA  
#12 B     2012-11-08 09:00:00  NA    NA  
#13 B     2012-11-08 10:00:00  36.5 -53.4
#14 B     2012-11-08 23:00:00  36.6 -53.4
#15 B     2012-11-09 00:00:00  NA    NA  
#16 B     2012-11-09 01:00:00  NA    NA  
#17 B     2012-11-09 02:00:00  NA    NA  
#18 B     2012-11-09 03:00:00  NA    NA  
#19 B     2012-11-09 04:00:00  NA    NA  
#20 B     2012-11-09 05:00:00  36.6 -53.5
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. Sometimes I will also have to run this code using minutes. For example, the time intervals would be every 30 minutes, and I would want to keep gaps of 1 hour/60 mins (two 30-min intervals), but not gaps that are more than that. Is it possible to adapt this for that? I've tried changing the units to "mins", the >10 to ">60" and leaving the "hour" in the second line, but that just gives me an NA line for every hour in the gap, when I really want an NA for every 30-min gap unless there are more than two 30-min gaps in that hour. Does that make sense?

Comment: I've edited my question to also ask for this

Comment: @jl748795 For that you need to change 2 things. 1) `group_by(grp = cumsum(difftime(datetime, lag(datetime, default = first(datetime)), units = 'mins') > 30), .add = TRUE)` 2) `complete(datetime = seq(min(datetime), max(datetime), by = '30 mins'))`

Comment: Thank you! This works in terms of getting 30 minute NA sets, but I still have gaps greater than 1 hour (i.e. four 30-min NAs in a row instead of capping it at two 30-min intervals. I was hoping to incorporate that into this code to make it easier to run this with various time intervals, but I suppose it can be done afterward.